# While loop not behaving as expected using Dates objects

Tags: javascript

Im making an array that stores a start time and times following that in 40 min intervals.

Basically check, add the start time to the array then increment repeat.

```
  //Array Of All Available times.
  var timeArray = [];
  //Start time this begins with 9:00
  var startTime = new Date(`date setup here`);
  //End Time this is 17:00
  var endTime = new Date(`date setup here`);
  while (startTime < endTime) {
    //Push Start Time to Array
    timeArray.push(startTime);
    //Add 40 minutes to startTime
    startTime = new Date(startTime.setMinutes(startTime.getMinutes() +40));
  }
```

Here are screenshots of the logs:

Start and end Times:

[image: img]

Log of Array:

[image: img2]

In the array I find it strange why the inital start time of 9 is not index 0 and why the last index is the end time which should of failed the while loop condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your loop:

```
while (startTime < endTime) {
    //Push Start Time to Array
    timeArray.push(startTime);
    //Add 40 minutes to startTime
    startTime = new Date(startTime.setMinutes(startTime.getMinutes() +40));
}
```

the last line *modifies* the `startTime` Date object *before* it assigns the new Date to the variable. Thus, when the `.push()` happens the date is correct, but it changes in that last line of the loop.

Instead, make a new date first and then change it:

```
while (startTime < endTime) {
    //Push Start Time to Array
    timeArray.push(startTime);
    //Add 40 minutes to startTime
    startTime = new Date(startTime);
    startTime.setMinutes(startTime.getMinutes() +40));
}
```

Comment: This was it thanks a lot for the suggestion it was such a small fix!